# how to serve index page from django instead of nginx static index page option

Tags: gunicorn

I am trying to deploy my webapp using NGINX-gunicorn-Djngo.The problem is when I open a root url(eg. www.xyz.com) in browser it shows default welcome page of NGINX but I want to serve my index page through django using proxy_pass.

when I am opening www.xyz.com// it works fine as the url matches with location block wiht pattern "/".Please suggest how can I make nginx redirect www.xyz.com to my gunicorn server.

find below my nginx.conf

```
user  ec2-user;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include         /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type    application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;

    #keepalive_timeout   0;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    #gzip                on;


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    upstream agencyhunt_server {
        server unix:/home/ec2-user/xyz/xyz.sock;  fail_timeout=10s;
        }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name www.taskuse.com;
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        access_log /home/ec2-user/agencyhunt/logs/nginx-access.log;
        error_log /home/ec2-user/agencyhunt/logs/nginx-error.log warn;
        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ec2-user/xyz/xyz.sock;

        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
        }

}
```